# get count between 2 known rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table, called Table1 which has 2 columns colA, which contains ints and colB, which contains strings.

colA has duplicate values. colA and colB together make a row unique.

I want to find the number of rows between 2 rows which are ordered by colA.
I have all the details of the 2 rows.

The following is the sql I have where the start row has colA value 10 and the end row has colA value 100:

```
select count(*) from Table1 where colA > 10 AND colA <= 100 ORDER BY colA ASC
```

But this only gives me a correct count if colA has only one 10.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `colA has only one 10`? Could you provide sample data?

Comment: have tried with separate values for colb and repeated values for cola and this query gives correct result.

Comment: Hi, this will only give me the count from when colA is greater than 10. but if there are multiple rows where colA is 10 and my row is in the middle of them then this doesn't give me my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first some data preparation

```
   create table TEST
(
    A int,
    B varchar(10)
);

insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(9,'B0');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(10,'B1');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(10,'B2');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(20,'B3');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(100,'B4');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(100,'B5');
insert into TEST (A,B) values 
(101,'B6');
```

Actually, i came up with even simplier solution. What is important is, if you wanna count
(FROM,TO) or  or 
and how to handle if there is no value where colA = FROM and or there is no value where colB=TO,
but:

```
select count(1) +
       coalesce((select  1 from TEST where A = 10 limit 1),0) +
       coalesce((select  1 from TEST where A = 100 limit 1),0) 
 from TEST where A > 10 and A < 100;
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.  First observation, the `order by` clause is totally unnecessary, because you are returning only one row (the `count(*)`).

Second, if a row is uniquely identified only by a combination of `colA` and `colB`, then there is no consistent definition of the rows between two values of `ColA`.  Consider:

```
9      B0
10     B1
10     B2
20     B3
100    B4
100    B5
101    B6
```

Is the number of rows between "10" and "100" exactly 1 (B3)?  Exactly 3 (B3, B4, and B4) as in your query)?  Exactly 5, from the first "10" to the last "100"?

The statement of your question is ambiguous.  Apart from the `order by`, your query is as good as any other attempt consistent with your definition.

Comment: Hi, using your example set- I want to count from the 2nd row (10, B1) to say the 1st 100 (100,B4). My query above will give me a count of 1. But I want a count of 2.

Comment: OH thanks for telling me about the order by- I'll sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique `colA` then you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT fieldName)` in sqlite, like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT colA) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE colA > 10 AND colA <= 100
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an exact count between 2 rows- not just the distinct values.